Changing Background Color of Django Admin List Display Based on status
I'm currently developing a Django project and I'm aiming to customize the background color of rows in the Django admin list display. I want the background color to change dynamically based on the status of each item. While researching online, I came across some examples, but I'm uncertain about how to integrate them effectively into my project. Could someone guide me through the process step by step?
I likely expected the rows in the Django admin list display for orders to have different background colors based on their status. Specifically, rows with the status 'new' should have a distinct visual appearance, perhaps with a specific background color such as red and others should be green.
Tried multiple things but nothing is working out.
